# Block Siri/Bixby/Google Assistant/Alexa/Cortana/... in home network

Tags: firewall

Ever since Apple released Siri, I was concerned about the fact that these "assistants" send recordings to some server, where the response is computed. They're not actually an "AI" that would actually pass a turing test and is able to understand you and respond accordingly - even though they're marketed as such.

Wishing for an "intelligent digital assistant" is neat and cool unless you realize that some company actually gets access to these recordings. Even worse, as unveiled in the past weeks/months, basically all companies not only store these recordings, they also have their employees listen to and correct the recordings.

I'll spare you the "1984 is here" crap at this point...

I don't own a dedicated device such as an Amazon Echo, but in my household there are Android phones (Samsung and other), iPhones, Win10-PCs, and Macbooks being used. All these devices/systems at least FEATURE some kind of "assistant" - and seeing it on my Samsung S10, they are quite pushy to make you use their system even when you deactivated the assistant in the settings.

With a variety of such devices in a house and how the current systems are activated, ultimately a more-or-less continuous recording of what happens in my house is stored in "some cloud", tethered to my internet access point. Great. Wow. I don't want that. It's not that I have to hide things, but...

Same is with companies: Imagine an office with - say - 20 people. Everyone is carrying/using a private phone, a company phone, and a computer. As a business owner, do you want recordings of all discussions/meetings on another company's server? Would you trust your employees to switch ALL their assistants off? Would you want to take that risk?

**What I want is to BLOCK all connections from any device in my network to any of those assistant back-ends. At the same time, I don't want to block other services of Apple/Amazon/Google/...**

This should be rather simple and one should be able to craft a small firewall rule to be installed on your router. So I searched. Interestingly, I only found discussions like "why would you want to block those?" and moreover "how do I unblock my Siri in my local/company network".

I am baffled! Does no one see an invasion of privacy? Can't be!

**So - anyone knows the IP address ranges of those services so I can block outgoing connections on my home/company router?**

Caveat: I am aware that this only works for devices in my network and does not restrict devices to use Siri etc. via the mobile networks. But I guess I can't do anything about that, can I?

Comment: You can ask each & every one of these companies to send you what data they have stored. From that you can quickly tell that such as Apple has far less actual personal info than say Facebook - all of which you voluntarily gave to them, & anyone else who can read it.

Comment: I am aware of this right to request an overview of your personal data. Still, this doesn't solve the problem! First of all, if I use Google services in general, it will be somewhat hard to distinguish between what comes from the Assistant and what from other services. Plus, I'd need to request deletion from all vendors periodically.
Second, if someone in my house uses Siri via my network, a recording is stored at Apple linked with my network ID. Still, this probably wouldn't be seen as MY personal data. So I wouldn't have any form of control here.

Comment: @Xenonite Did you ever find your answer? I'm in the same boat as you. I've always disabled them completely on my own devices.  But with the Google Assistant being shrunk to be able to run on a phone, I'm finally interested in investigating being able to have it work offline only and "just be broken" for anything that requires a data connection. Now, I'm wanting to block all of them from being able to ever "phone home."

Comment: No, I unfortunately haven't found a solution. Would love to see one though. Ideally as a automatically updated solution to install on a fritzbox router